# Intellij Idea needs Python

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Intellij Idea was working. Then it happened to remember about Python.

```
java: Cannot find JDK 'Python 3.8 (venv)' for module 'marketing3'
```

I have cleared the cache and reboot my computer.
Also I did Restore IDE settings.

I do have projects in Python (developed in PyCharm). But what has it to do with my Java project?

By the way, another project starts.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Try to close the IDE, and delete all **.iml** files and the **.idea** folder from the project root. Then [re-import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html) the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do the following steps to resolve it:

- Close the IDE
- Open the project root directory in the OS file manager and delete all `*.iml` files and the `.idea` directory
- [Re-import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html) the project